# How to stop slick-carousel in cypress

Tags: cypress, carousel

I need to stop this carousel in order to perform validation on it

Tried to set autoplay=false

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoplay function is based on `setInterval()` which is able to be controlled by Cypress.

See the Cypress documentation for [clock](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock)

> cy.clock() overrides native global functions related to time allowing them to be controlled synchronously via cy.tick() or the yielded clock object. This includes controlling:
>
> - setTimeout
> - clearTimeout
> - **setInterval**
> - clearInterval
> - Date Objects

So you should be able to freeze the carousel by putting the `cy.clock()` command at the top of your test, or before the `cy.visit()` page load.

In case you want to test the second slide and the third slide, etc, you can issue a `cy.tick(5000)` to move the autoplay on for one slide each time, since you configured `autoplaySpeed: 5000`.